# Declaring a struct in a class

Tags: c++, class, struct

I created a class called `Text`, and one of its members is a `std::vector` of `Pal_freq`, a `struct` declared inside the `class`.

I am getting those errors:

> error: ‘Pal_freq’ does not name a type
>      bool criteri (const Pal_freq& p1, const Pal_freq& p2);
>
> error: ‘Pal_freq’ does not name a type
>      bool criteri (const Pal_freq& p1, const Pal_freq& p2);
>
> error: ‘Pal_freq’ was not declared in this scope
>      vector consultar_taula_freq();
>
> error: template argument 1 is invalid
>      vector consultar_taula_freq();

Here is the code:

```
class Text {
 public:

  struct Pal_freq {
  int freq;
  string pal;
  };

  vector <Pal_freq> taula;
};
```

Comment: [Works here](https://ideone.com/5OUfd6). Did you forget to `#include <string>` or `#include <vector>`?

Comment: Hello Pau, to get better help you should include the error message. "Doesn't work" is not  very telling.

Comment: your error messages do not correlate with your code

Comment: You are clearly not including the whole code. My guess is you aren't qualifying the name `Text::Pal_freq` when you use it outside of `Text`.

Comment: Questions _seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")_ must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Im not including the whole class, its from a school project and I dont want to have the complete class posted publicly in the internet. There are a lot of functions as the ones in the errors and all of them get them same error:  Pal_freq was not declared.

Comment: @Pau, I didn't say you should include the **whole** class, please read my comment again! Read the link on how to create a **minimal** and **complete** example. That doesn't just mean dump the entire piece of code here. Read the links and the guides on how to use this site, it will save you time and save us time, so you get better answers (but in this case I already gave you the answer below ... but please read how to use this site properly!)

Answer (score 3):

The error messages are not coming from the tiny piece of ode you showed (the definition of the struct), they are coming from other pieces of code that you *didn't* show us (i.e. where you try to use the nested struct).

Because it is declared inside `Text` you need to qualify its name when you refer to it outside the scope of `Text`, so you need to refer to it as  `Text::Pal_freq` e.g.

```
bool criteri (const Text::Pal_freq& p1, const Text::Pal_freq& p2);
```

Please read the "how to ask" guidelines on the site, and make sure you include all the necessary code for us to help you.

Comment: Thank you! bool criteri is inside Text, should I use Text:: anyway?

Comment: _"bool criteri is inside Text"_ No it isn't. Not in the code you showed us. This is why we can't help you unless you ask better questions. How do you expect people to explain why you get errors for `criteri` if you don't show `criteri`?! Maybe you need to move the declaration of `Pal_freq` before the member functions that try to use it. But show the code, or we're just guessing, and your question should be closed.